# Getting WFS when click on parcel

Tags: wms, wfs, openlayers-2

When i open some page, i want to show only WMS layers. When clicking on some parcel, as response, it should call WFS, and show information of that parcel, and only that one. How can i manage that with Openlayers 2.13?

Comment: You may also do that with WMS and GetFeatureInfo. Check if server supports GML or GeoJSON as INFO_FORMAT. GeoServers by default do.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write a custom control that does that thing. Ive written a tutorial on the topic, so check it out :)
http://codentonic.net/2015/04/02/custom-openlayer-control/
if you have any questions feel free to ask me

Comment: Wow, you really did a nice work. I'll try simpler solution, and if it doesn't work, i'll call for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature:

```
var your_control = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
            protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(your_wms_layer),
            box: true,
            hover: true,
            multipleKey: "shiftKey",
            toggleKey: "ctrlKey"
        });
```

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/getfeature-wfs.html

Comment: What about pop-up? i still haven't seen it, so i did something wrong or there is nothing to show. By pop-up i mean informations about feature.

Comment: if you register the featureselected-event you have got the feature with it's attributes.This you can use to "fill" a popup. http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html